# How to write a DirectX audio push source

Tags: c++, winapi, filter, directx

I want to create a DirectX 'filter' that sources a single channel of audio. I have seen the Platform SDK sample projects, but the downside there is that those require the ATL library.

Is there a way to create DirectX filters *without* resorting to ATL or MFC? I.e., some way using only gcc (e.g., MinGW) and other actually free tools?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the filter has to be a COM component. You can, sort of, write those from most compilers, if need be.

However, the boilerplate that would involve would be *incredible*, I had a 18kloc codebase that turned into 25kloc when turned into COM components (ended up turning it back just because there was more boilerplate COM than actual code for small plugins).

MFC isn't necessary or always involved in writing COM components, that I know of.

ATL helps simplify that greatly, by providing templates and functions to handle a lot of the details at compile-time. You may be able to use it from GCC, but I'm not sure what would happen; I doubt it would work well, though it might work.

Without ATL, you need MIDL and to generate the code from there. That is possible with free tools, it's done in a few places in the Wine project; you may check the code and toolchains there.

No matter where you do it, it'll be a pain, and a serious pain if you insist on using "actually free" tools for it (as they're not particularly designed to work with COM).

Comment: yeah I realize I'm swimming against the current on this, DirectX being what it is. I live in hope.

Comment: It does work, and you can do it with free tools, but it's a royal pain. Wine would be the first place to look for examples; there's a solid chance there's code to do just this.

Answer (score 0):

If you had DirectShow filter in mind, the best starting point would be [PushSource Windows SDK Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which generates video and making it generate audio.

Also note that DirectShow bases classes are one of the earliest COM bases and they do not use ATL/MFC. The base classses themselves are also included with Windows SDK.

Comment: In the platform SDK I have, the three samples projects I tried all choked looking for atls.lib, which, oddly, they were trying to find within the Platform SDK directory itself. PSDK in question is the 2003 version. Was the expectation that one somehow 'installs' the PSDK into MSVC such that MSVC would have added the necessary file(s) into the PSDK?

Comment: I checked much earlier set - [DirectX 9.0 SDK Update (February 2005) Extras](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=12518), it also has this PushSource sample there. atlbase.h is mentioned once, through I don't remember where exactly it is used, and some basic ATL stuff is duplicated in code, so I think it's not difficult to make it link without ATL as you want.